# Mockito : Calling real implementation

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to write unit test for my controller class. But instead of mocking `EmployeeBussinessLogic`  it is invoking real method call.

```
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value="/GetAllEmployeeDetails", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public List<Employee> GetAllEmployeeDetails() {

        EmployeeBussinessLogic empbl = new EmployeeBussinessLogic();
        return empbl.GetAllEmployeeDetails();

   }
```

following is the `EmployeeBussinessLogic` class

```
public class EmployeeBussinessLogic {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    public EmployeeBussinessLogic()
    {
         employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAOImpl();
    }

    public EmployeeBussinessLogic(EmployeeDAO explicityEmployeeDAO)
    {
        employeeDAO = explicityEmployeeDAO;
    }

    public List<Employee>  GetAllEmployeeDetails()
    {
        List<Employee> EmployeeList = employeeDAO.listOfEmployees();

        String text = "";

        for(Employee emp : EmployeeList)
        {
            text =  "Emp ID = " + emp.getEmployeeId() +
                " Emp Age = " + emp.getEmployeeAge() + 
                " Emp Name = " + emp.getEmployeeName() + 
                " Emp Salary = " + emp.getEmployeeSalary().toString().trim() + "\n";

            System.out.println(text);
        }
        return EmployeeList ;
    }
}
```

Following is my controller test code

```
public class ControllerTestWithMockito {

    @Mock
    EmployeeBussinessLogic empBusLgcObj;

    @Mock
    EmployeeDAO mockEmployeeDAO;

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    Controller ctrlObj;

    @Before
    public void create()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        empList.add(new Employee(1, "Emp1", 23, 1000));
        empList.add(new Employee(2, "Emp2", 24, 2000));

        Mockito.when(empBusLgcObj.GetAllEmployeeDetails()).thenReturn(empList);     
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllEmployeeDetailstest() {

        final List<Employee> expectedEmpList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        expectedEmpList.add(new Employee(1, "Emp1", 23, 1000));
        expectedEmpList.add(new Employee(2, "Emp2", 24, 2000));

        final List<Employee> actualEmpList = ctrlObj.GetAllEmployeeDetails();
        Assert.assertTrue(actualEmpList.size() == expectedEmpList.size());
        Assert.assertTrue(actualEmpList.equals(expectedEmpList));
    }

}
```

Comment: you can use MockitoJUnitRunner to make your code more annotation based - check @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to this:

```
Mockito.doReturn(empList).when(empBusLgcObj).GetAllEmployeeDetails();
```

That prevents calling the real method in spies

Comment: The line that needs to be changed is Mockito.when(empBusLgcObj.GetAllEmployeeDetails()).thenReturn(empList);

Comment: Also, your brackets are wrong, the replacement code is doReturn(empList).when(empBusLgcObj).GetAllEmployeeDetails();

Comment: Thats correct, thanks for spotting this out.. was putting my answer to fast and followed the standard when() procedure semantics

Comment: Still it is going into the actual function call.

Comment: Check out the @Andreas_D answer. In combination with mine the solution will work.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, do not create a new instance with `new`. This code is untestable. Use injection instead:

```
public class Controller {

    @Inject
    private EmployeeBusinessLogic empbl;

    @RequestMapping(value="/GetAllEmployeeDetails", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public List<Employee> GetAllEmployeeDetails() {

        return empbl.GetAllEmployeeDetails();
    }
```

Comment: The question was not about the Controller, but about mocking EmployeeBussinessLogic

Comment: The problem is that he wants to spy the EBL but because the EBL is not injected but created inside the method, the controller will never use the spy. @InjectMocks requires that Mockito can do some injection, either field, method or constructor injection. And regarding the question: he wondered why his mock (spy) is never called. Mine is the answer and solution.

Comment: Ok, I understand your answer now, but it is not a complete solution to his problem, there are 2 bugs in his code.  Your answer solves one of them.  Mockito sets fields through injection as explained at http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.3/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html and objects instantiated with new will indeed not be mocked by Mockito.

Answer (score 0):

Andreas_D is right that you should use injection instead of instantiating the object that you want to mock in the method `GetAllEmployeeDetails`.

I only want to add that you should prefer constructor injection. It makes your code more flexible.

```
public class Controller{

    private final EmployeeBussinessLogic  employeeBusinessLogic;

    @Autowired
    public Controller(final EmployeeBussinessLogic  employeeBusinessLogic){
        this.employeeBusinessLogic = employeeBusinessLogic;
    }

    ...

}
```

You can also choose to delegate the injection to another class. This can be usefull when the classes `EmployeeBusinessLogic` and `EmployeeDAO` are located in another library which your web layer uses.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig{


    @Bean
    public EmployeeBusinessLogic employeeBusinessLogic{
        return new EmployeeBusinessLogicImpl(new EmployeeDAOImpl());
    }

}
```

EmployeeBusinessLogic can then be implemented without annotations in your library.

```
public class EmployeeBussinessLogic {

    private final EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    public EmployeeBussinessLogic(final EmployeeDAO employeeDAO)
    {
         this.employeeDAO = employeeDAO;
    }

    ...
}
```